# Nest 3rd generation UK Install Terminals 4, 5 and 6 are used to connect cables that switch your domestic hot water on or off

Tags: hot-water, nest

Nest 3rd generation UK Install Terminals 4, 5 and 6 are used to connect cables that switch your domestic hot water on or off. Hi have my new nest 3rd gen installed heating is working great for radiators. Its the Hot water i'm stuck on. any help appreciated. [image]

Comment: Please state your question clearly - do you want to know which terminals in the Nest box are used to control the central heating? Do you not have an installation manual? Have you read [How to install your Nest Learning Thermostat](https://nest.com/support/article/How-to-install-your-Nest-Learning-Thermostat)?

Answer (score 1):

From the following documents it seems to me that 2 & 3 (common and call-for-heat) are used to provide power to the zone valve (which presumably then provides power to pump and boiler as in a conventional system)

This assumes you installed the Nest-display so that it repurposed the old 240V thermostat wiring for 12V power from the Nest Heat-Link unit (T1,T2).

You should check this with the installation manual supplied by Nest or using the online configuration tools on the Nest web-site.

- [Nest Thermostat Installation Guide](http://www.directheatingsupplies.co.uk/pdfs/Nest%20Thermostat%20Installation%20Guide%20UK.pdf)
- [How to install your Nest Learning Thermostat](https://nest.com/support/article/How-to-install-your-Nest-Learning-Thermostat)